# Swedish Knife ? What is this?

Tags: knives

I was looking at the website for Francis Batt, a French culinary boutique (my boning knife is from there, great product IMO, so I'm a fan). I noticed a knife there called a [«couteau suédois»](https://www.francisbatt.com/produits/couteau-suedois-22-cm-manche-noir-rivets-laiton) or Swedish knife, however googling this in both French and English yielded no real info.

What is a Swedish knife ?

Comment: On the page you linked to it shows this knife under fish knives, specifically salmon.

Comment: @DebbieM., I saw it linked from another page on the site and didn't see the site tree

Answer (score 5):

That is the kind of knife you would use to slice gravlax (salt and sugar cured salmon) or possibly smoked salmon into thin, large slices. You need a long, narrow, flexible blade to cut the salmon nicely. I have never seen them referred to as a "Swedish knife" anywhere else though. In Swedish stores they would be sold as filleting knives.